# Modular exponentiation and two primes

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, cryptography

> Given two primes $11$ and $5$, find all $\alpha> 1$ such that $$\alpha^{5} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$$

What theorem will help me to find it out?

Comment: Try "everything," effectively there are only $9$ candidates. These are the quadratic residues other than $1$, but using that is unnecessary.

Comment: There's no way to give a helpful answer without knowing your background. For example, some number theory textbooks have a theorem where you can simply plug in $5$ and $11$ to some formula to produce the answer. Is that what you want? Or do you want to understand why such a formula works? Or to work it out by hand?

Comment: A formula to produce the output is fine, with some tip about why it works or some reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As $2^2\equiv4,2^5\equiv-1\pmod{11}$

$\implies2$ is a primitive root $\pmod{11}$

So taking Discrete Logarithm wrt $2$ on $$\alpha^5\equiv1\pmod{11}$$

$5$ind$_2\alpha\equiv0\pmod{\phi(11)}\implies$ind$_2\alpha\equiv0\pmod2$

$\implies\alpha\equiv2^{2n}\pmod{11}$ where $0\le2n<10$